# Rewrite URL with one mandatory query string and another optional one

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite the following URL:

```
http://domain.com/quiz/1/234
```

To

```
http://domain.com/quiz.php?id=1&uid=234
```

I have the following rule in htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^quiz/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ quiz.php?id=$1&uid=$2 [L]
```

Using the above rule, both query strings must exist in the URL to be rewritten; I want to change this behaviour and make the second query string (`234` in the example) to be optional so that if I call the following URL:

```
http://domain.com/quiz/1
```

It will redirect to:

```
http://domain.com/quiz.php?id=1
```

And also if I call:

```
http://domain.com/quiz/1/234
```

It will redirect to:

```
http://domain.com/quiz.php?id=1&uid=234
```

I can achieve this using 2 separate rules but I think there would be a more correct way to achieve it.

Comment: The most simple is to merely make the 2nd capture optional: `^quiz/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)?$`, and keep the replacement unchanged. So `http://domain.com/quiz/1` will be redirected to `http://domain.com/quiz.php?id=`, which is pretty legal. Then called script and will then easily take care of empty `$_GET['uid']`.

Comment: @cFreed I tried adding the `?` like you suggested and now the rule is `RewriteRule ^quiz/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)?$ quiz.php?id=$1&uid=$2 [L]` but this is still not working and returns 404 error

Comment: "returns 404 error": from which original url, and which is the resulting (404) url?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^quiz/(\d+)(?:/(\d+))?/?$ quiz.php?id=$1&uid=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

`(?:/(\d+))?` makes 2nd part totally optional with an optional trailing slash.